# Is it safe to turn urls into links?

Tags: php, xss, sanitization, htmlpurifier, html-entities

I want to turn urls in the user comments, into links.

I don't have time to test bloated anti-xss libraries like HTML Purify, so I wouldn't be allowing any html tags.

I just want to make everything go through htmlentities() and nl2br(), and then use preg_replace() to find urls and turn them into links ('a' html tags).

Is it unsafe to grab the urls I find and put them inside href='' ?

If not, what can I do about it?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by URL and by safe.

Comment: "I don't have time to test bloated anti-xss libraries like HTML Purify".  Hopefully whatever libraries you *do* use have already been tested, so you can simply use them.  Why duplicate effort and test someone else's code?

Comment: You can do that. Most blogs do it. Even SO does it

Comment: Indeed your approach to escaping is sound and sufficient. There is no inherent insecurity in URLs. Just limit the allowed url length (<300).

Comment: @JohnP I know it's done everywhere, but I can't tell how it is done just by watching the resulting html. And even if I could, the fact that it is used everywhere doesn't mean a thing. Blogs get hacked everyday

Comment: @Gumbo If we are talking about XSS, what do you think I mean with 'safe'? And if we are talking about.. Wait, URL does not have multiple meanings, does it? @Merlyn Morgan-Graham I can't just pick random libraries and use them because 'hopefuly they have been tested'. And even if it was a well known and tested library, I have to make some basic tests myself, eg: Test that it actually turns the urls into links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be safe. If you wonder how, here is a function I use for this (I simplified it for the purpose of this post):

```
function formatPost($string) {
    return nl2br(
        preg_replace_callback(
            '~https?://([^/\s]+)(?:/((?>[/\w]+|\S(?!\s|$))*))?~',
            function($matches) {
                $url  = $matches[0];
                $host = $matches[1];
                $path = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : '';
                $follow = false;

                if ('' == $path) {
                    $text = $host;
                } elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == $host) {
                    $text = $path;
                    $follow = true;
                } else {
                    $text = $host . '/' . $path;
                }

                return '<a href="' . $url . '"' . (!$follow ? ' rel="nofollow"' : '') . '>' . $text . '</a>';
            },
            htmlspecialchars($string)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: -1 This function is flawed: `formatPost('http://"><script>alert("XSS")</script>foo')`

Comment: @Gumbo: No, it isn't: As I have mentioned in my last sentence, this function accepts already escaped input (because I use it as a `pre_escape` filter for Twig). I changed my post to include a `htmlspecialchars` and removed the note.